# App submittion from clients side

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am developing an application which is going to be branded to for different clients. For some clients I will release the application myself using my developer account @ apple, but some clients want to release the application using their own developer account.
Off course they can create an account for me which I can build the application with, or I could give them the source code of my application and let them do it them selfs. 
BUT, what if I want to do neither of those solutions? Is there some way that I could build the application on my computer for the client with maybe the Bundle identifier that doesn't exist yet? (e.g. `com.somecompany.appName`)?

I am skeptic to "give" away my source code to the client.

How can I share my app with the client without sharing the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client has an Intel Mac and an iOS developer account, then one common way to do this is to put your app's code mostly inside a static shared library, with a few pages of wrapper code to start it.  Then give the client an Xcode project containing the library object code (of your "secret" ingredients) plus the public wrapper source code.  The client can launch Xcode, select their Distribution provision, hit build, then submit the results.

This technique optionally also allows the client to modify icons, appIDs, etc., but still not see the source to your shared library.

Comment: Awesome, I think this is what I am looking for. Do you have any links on how to create a static shared library which you recommend? Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the login provided by your client to do it yourself without giving away your source code. Or just request a distr cert en sent a zip back to your client.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the first solution might not always be available. The last solution is off course an option, but what I meant with the question is if there is some way to pre-build an application without signing it, and sign it later.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to have all your information ready. Appstore Submitting Template I use. http://loughnanedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/app-store-submitting-template.html